# Laravel Backpack 6 ckeditor 5 view source button

Tags: ckeditor5, laravel-backpack

I'm using backpack 6 with ckeditor 5...
How do I add the 'view source' button onto the ckeditor navbar?

and also allow div and class tags to be added in the wysiwyg without them being stripped out?

i've tried installing it using: `npm install @ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing`
and then using it in the field with:

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'body',
    'type' => 'ckeditor',
    'extra_plugins' => [
        'source-editing',
    ]
]);
```

but it can't find it

```
plugincollection.ts:396 Uncaught (in promise) CKEditorError: plugincollection-plugin-not-found {"plugin":"source-editing"}
```

any help would be great, ta

Comment: placing it in `extra_plugins` is in my opinion wrong, as you want to have it in the toolbar: `editor.config.toolbar.items: [..., sourceEditing, ...]`.  My notation is a bit different, as I use another environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add more plugins to CKEditor follow the guide [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/issues/559#issuecomment-1630673757)

Comment: Great... many thanks.
Do you know how to allow class tags in ckeditor?